# Why should a graph with n vertices have n-1 edges?

Tags: graph-theory

I understand the proof of this theorem. But can someone visually explain this to me? Why should we have n-1 edges?

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you mean why should a tree with n vertices have n-1 edges.

A tree is defined as a graph with no loops. (Multiple definitions may exist)

Take a tree (it might be a single vertex) and add an edge to some vertex of it. As you cannot link this edge to an already existing vertex (otherwise you create a loop), you need to link this edge to a new vertex. This way each time you add an edge, you also add a vertex.

This "proof" being constructive, I hope that it makes it more clear for you.

Comment: There is a little technical problem with forward induction in this case (which occurs often in combinatorics): to do induction by adding, you must also prove that you can reach every possible configuration. To avoid this, one should subtract: it is easy to prove that a tree with more than one vertex as at least one leaf. Removing the leaf, you remove one vertex and one edge and you can use induction on the tree you obtain (must also prove that is still a tree).

Comment: Indeed, sorry for the mistake and thanks for the clarification.